# Не компилируется класс

Tags: java

Только начал изучать яву по книжке, там есть небольшой пример кода представленный ниже.

```
public class Player {
    int number;
    public void guess() {
        number = (int) (Math.random * 10);
        System.out.println("I think it's " + number);
    }
}
```

при попытке скомпилировать через cmd, выдаёт следующее

[image]

Comment: Math.random() - это метод, а не свойство. Скобки добавьте

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, действительно не хватало скобок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.random() скобки!!!!! Это метод

Answer (score 1):

Math.random это метод класса Math. 
[Вот более подробно](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/methods.php)

```
number = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку)